# solve a coupled ODE of euler angels Rotation vector of a body

Tags: matlab, robotics

i'm trying to solve coupled ODEs by using matlab ode45 function:

[image]

Here is my function called 'Rot' to describe these ODE's for using matlab ode45.

```
function omega= Rot(t,y)
omega(2,1)=(0.03*sin(3*t)*((cos(Y(1)))^2)+0.002*t^3*sin(y(1)))...
/-((cos(Y(1)))^2)+((sin(Y(1)))^2);
omega(1,1)=((0.002*t^2-omega(2,1)*sin(y(1)))...
/-cos(y(3))*sin(y(2)))*cos(y(2))+0.01*t^2+0.3*t;
omega(3,1)=(0.002*t^2-omega(2,1)*sin(y(1)))...
/-cos(y(3))*sin(y(2));
```

but I'm getting "Not enough input arguments." error.

Comment: Yes. It is because of that.

Comment: `omega(3,1)` is a function of `omega(2,1)`, which is itself a function of `omega(3,1)`, so by combining the last two equations you should be able to get an expression of `omega(3,1)` which depends only `t` and `y`, and which you can then inject into the equation for `omega(1,1)`.

Comment: @am304   thanks for your command, I tried it but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What exactly didn't work? There's no reason mathematically why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @am304  I checked the problem again, there was a mistake in the equations, in the 3rd one, there is an 'omega(2,1)' multiplied by sin(psi). i changed my code to decouple the equations as you told so, but now i'm receiving this error: 
                  Not enough input arguments.

Comment: Can you update your question with the updated code & error message so that we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: How are you calling Rot? Is the error arising from the Rot call or the ode45 call?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so by expressing `theta_dot` as a function of the other variables in equation (3) and injecting the result in equation (2), I get (pseudo-code):

`phi_dot = (0.03*sin(psi)*sin(3*t) - 0.002*t^2 * cos(psi)) / (sin(theta)*(cos(psi))^2 + sin(theta) * sin(psi) * sin(phi))`

So makes that the first equation of your ODE file as it only depends on time and the state vector.

Then your second equation in the ODE file is:

`psi_dot = -phi_dot * cos(theta) + 0.01*t^2 + 0.3*t`

which is OK because you've calcuated `phi_dot` in the previous equation.

And finally the last equation in your ODE file:

`theta_dot = (-0.03*sin(3*t) + phi_dot * sin(theta) * sin(phi)) / cos(psi);`

which is also OK because you have calculated `phi_dot` in your first equation.

You can then pass this to the ODE solver and it should work. (do check my maths though)